# Getting error while build cordova project in android

Tags: cordova

Getting error while build cordova project in android. I believe I am getting below error because of proxy. Can you please assist me to setup proxy for gradle?

or please provide alternative solution for this. below is the error.

```
Error: cmd: Command failed with exit code 1 Error outpu
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.RuntimeException:
tion: services.gradle.org
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManage
essManager.java:78)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install.createDist(Instal
        at org.gradle.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(W
        at org.gradle.wrapper.GradleWrapperMain.main(Gr
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: services.grad
        at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Abs
:184)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocket
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocket
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:589)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:538)
        at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClien
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpC
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpC
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.<init>(HttpClien
        at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.New(HttpClient.j
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
onnection.java:1209)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
ection.java:1157)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
ction.java:1032)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
.java:966)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
nnection.java:1546)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.
nection.java:1474)
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.downloadInternal
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Download.download(Downloa
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.ja
        at org.gradle.wrapper.Install$1.call(Install.ja
        at org.gradle.wrapper.ExclusiveFileAccessManage
essManager.java:65)
        ... 3 more
```

Comment: try removing and adding platform again,then build

Comment: tried, still it is not working

Comment: can you provide me detailed error message ?